# How to handle columns of lists in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the process of merging data I often end up with columns of lists (for example a line in a left table has several matches in a right table)

let's define

```
DT = data.table(x=list(c(1,2),c(3,4,5)),y=list(c(T,T),c(T,F,T)),z=c(1,2),N=c(1L,2L))
#       x               y z N
#1:   1,2       TRUE,TRUE 1 1
#2: 3,4,5 TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2
```

1. Is it possible to modify in-place aka `update` `x` to `x[y]` ?

I can do it but not updating (and it looks ugly) as:

```
DT1 = DT[,list(x=list(unlist(x)[unlist(y)])),by=N]
DT = cbind(DT[,x:=NULL],DT1[,list(x)])
                 y z N   x
1:       TRUE,TRUE 1 1 1,2
2: TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2 3,5
```

Now let's suppose I define `mySet = c(1,5)` and want to check that values of column `x %in% mySet`

1. How can I do this ?

   ```
                    y z N   x isInMySet
   1:       TRUE,TRUE 1 1 1,2 TRUE,FALSE
   2: TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2 3,5 FASLE,TRUE
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an answer for your earlier question to realize that you had deleted the question. Here's how you can update (the answer for your first part).

```
DT[, x := list(list(unlist(x)[unlist(y)])), by=N]

#      x               y z N
# 1: 1,2       TRUE,TRUE 1 1
# 2: 3,5 TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2
```

And for your second part:

```
DT[, isInMySet := list(list(unlist(x) %in% mySet)), by=N]

#      x               y z N  isInMySet
# 1: 1,2       TRUE,TRUE 1 1 TRUE,FALSE
# 2: 3,5 TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2 FALSE,TRUE
```

(or alternatively)

```
DT[, isInMySet := lapply(x, function(x) x %in% mySet)]
```

Comment: Well done mate ! I find the use of lists cumbersome in data.table

Comment: The problem is not really on lists, rather that the LHS and RHS must have the same data type when updating (`:=`). If you for example do `dt <- data.table(x=1:10, g=rep(1:3, c(4,3,3)))` and do `dt[, m := median(x), by=g]` you would get the same error as the median of some values are `integer` and some are `numeric`. So you'll have to use `as.numeric(median(x))` there. Similar issue here to get the value as `list`.

Comment: +1 too. @statquant Suggestions how to make it less cumbersome are always very welcome.

Comment: You refer to my previous, deleted post. I agree, and BTW if somebody know what I should do to change the LHS type in a `:=` that would be helpful

Comment: @statquant Not sure what you mean by changing LHS type. The LHS is a column name. You can change the type of a column using `colName:=as.integer(colName)` for example?

Comment: @statquant I suppose I find `list` columns awkward too, truth be told. `list` of `list` sometimes needs a bit of trial and error, so I know what you mean.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: What I meant by LHS needs clarification, what I was trying to do is to update a column of lists by the column formed by each first element of each list. So a column of list would become a column of numeric for example...

Comment: @statquant `DT[,col:=sapply(col,'[',1)]`?

Answer (score 4):

Another approach :

```
DT
       x               y z N
1:   1,2       TRUE,TRUE 1 1
2: 3,4,5 TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2

DT[,x2:=mapply(`[`,x,y,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)]
DT
       x               y z N  x2
1:   1,2       TRUE,TRUE 1 1 1,2
2: 3,4,5 TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2 3,5

DT[,isInMySet:=lapply(x2,`%in%`,c(1,5))]
DT
       x               y z N  x2  isInMySet
1:   1,2       TRUE,TRUE 1 1 1,2 TRUE,FALSE
2: 3,4,5 TRUE,FALSE,TRUE 2 2 3,5 FALSE,TRUE
```