# How can I key by a column of lists in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894562/how-to-handle-columns-of-lists-in-data-table/14894631#comment20890141_14894631), I have another question about columns of lists in `data.table`.

```
DT = data.table(x=list(c(1,2),c(1,2),c(3,4,5)))
```

It seems you can't key on a column of lists.

```
DT[,y:=.I,by=x]
Erreur dans `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(y, .I), by = x) :
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (2,2,3). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (3).
```

I thought I could with lists of same length but:

```
DT = data.table(x=list(c(1,2),c(1,2),c(3,5)))
DT[,y:=.I,by=x]
Erreur dans `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(y, .I), by = x) :
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (2,2,2). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (3).
```

Is there a workaround? If not what about a feature request?

Comment: yes, `list` is not allowed (currently) as a key column. You get this message when you do `setkey(DT, "x")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this as a workaround:

```
DT[, y := which(DT$x %in% x), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
```

This returns the first matching index always, which will serve as a group id.

You should do something like this:

```
DT[, psnInGrp := seq_along(x), by=y]

#        x y psnInGrp
# 1:   1,2 1        1
# 2:   1,2 1        2
# 3: 3,4,5 3        1
```

Comment: Not sure about `by=1:nrow(DT)` in general. May be faster to use `lapply` and friends in `j`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, Is it possible to select row-by-row without doing `1:nrow(DT)`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but yes. `lapply` can be used in `j` on columns as well as on `.SD`.

Comment: What I mean is, if you want to take each element of x one by one, that is, `(1,2)`, then the next `1,2` and then `3,4,5` and perform an operation (and there is no key set), like here using `which(..)`, how would you do it without using `1:nrow(dt)` in `by`?

Comment: I guess it comes down to: how do you use `lapply` to find identical elements in a `list` and assign them all a unique value? In this case, the first two can get say `1` and the 3rd element of `x` would get a unique value of `2`. I can't think of an easier way than `which(.)` using `lapply`...

Comment: something like this, maybe? `DT[, grp:=lapply(x, function(u) which(DT$x %in% list(u))[1])]`

Comment: I'm thoroughly lost now :)  Why is there a `DT$x` inside `j` (both in answer and in comments)?  I didn't know `%in%` accepted `list` actually, but looking at `?%in%` I see it says that lists are converted to `character` first (efficiency?).  I'm not sure how a list column could ever be used as a key : each cell can be different type, embedded data.table even. If every cell is a vector of the same length, then it could be a multi column key instead.

Comment: hmmm, I'll frame my answer as a question (just so that I don't repeat myself). Given a list of vectors, say, list(1:2, 1:2, 3:5), how do you group them? By group, I mean something similar to `factor` for vectors. If I were to do `factor(c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4))` I'd get its levels as `1,2,3,4`. How to do this on the list and in addition, store the levels as another column (without using DT$x)?