# Filtering R data.table by the contents of a column of lists

Tags: r, data.table

Similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14894562/8034603) to examining columns of lists in data.tables. I have a column of lists that I would like to filter the rows of a data.table `b` by. In this case, I have a list of terms `c` that I would like to look for in column `V1` of `b`. I can use the other solution to make a second logical list column, and then filter `b` by summing the logical list, but is there any way to accomplish this in one step without creating an extra column?

```r
library(data.table)

# make data
a = data.table(ggplot2::mpg)[, .(year, cyl, displ)]
b = a[, list(list(year)), by=.(cyl, displ)]

# filter by list
c = c("1999", "2000")
b[, isInMySet := lapply(V1, function(x) x %in% c)]
b[lapply(b$isInMySet, sum) > 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `any` to your comparison so it returns a single TRUE or FALSE for each list. I've used `vapply` to try to speed things up a fraction again:

```
b[vapply(V1, \(x) any(x %in% c), FUN.VALUE=TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized solution using `findInterval` is a bit clunkier than `vapply`, but it can be a bit faster:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  findInterval = b[unique(findInterval(which(unlist(V1) %in% 1999:2000), c(0L, cumsum(lengths(V1))), 0, 1, 1))],
  vapply = b[vapply(V1, \(x) any(x %in% 1999:2000), FUN.VALUE=TRUE)],
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>          expr   min    lq    mean median    uq   max neval
#>  findInterval  90.2  95.3 103.616  97.60 100.4 323.0   100
#>        vapply 123.5 130.5 138.566 133.15 138.0 232.1   100
```